# Error when building docker image for jupyter spark notebook

Tags: docker, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to build Jupyter notebook in docker following the guide here:
https://github.com/cordon-thiago/airflow-spark
and got an error with exit code: 8.
I ran:

```
$ docker build --rm --force-rm -t jupyter/pyspark-notebook:3.0.1 .
```

the building stops at the code:

```
RUN wget -q $(wget -qO- https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz\?as_json | \
    python -c "import sys, json; content=json.load(sys.stdin); print(content['preferred']+content['path_info'])") && \
    echo "${spark_checksum} *spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" | sha512sum -c - && \
    tar xzf "spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" -C /usr/local --owner root --group root --no-same-owner && \
    rm "spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz"
```

with error message like below:

```
 => ERROR [4/9] RUN wget -q $(wget -qO- https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz?as_json |     python -c "import sys, json; content=json.load(sys.stdin);   2.3s
------
 > [4/9] RUN wget -q $(wget -qO- https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz?as_json |     python -c "import sys, json; content=json.load(sys.stdin); print(content[
'preferred']+content['path_info'])") &&     echo "F4A10BAEC5B8FF1841F10651CAC2C4AA39C162D3029CA180A9749149E6060805B5B5DDF9287B4AA321434810172F8CC0534943AC005531BB48B6622FBE228DDC *spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.
tgz" | sha512sum -c - &&     tar xzf "spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz" -C /usr/local --owner root --group root --no-same-owner &&     rm "spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz":
------
executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -c wget -q $(wget -qO- https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz\
?as_json |     python -c "import sys, json; content=json.load(sys.stdin); print(content['preferred']+content['path_info'])") &&     echo "${spark_checksum} *spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_
VERSION}.tgz" | sha512sum -c - &&     tar xzf "spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz" -C /usr/local --owner root --group root --no-same-owner &&     rm "spark-${APACHE_SPARK_VERSION}
-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz"]: exit code: 8
```

Really appreciate if someone can enlighten me on this. Thanks!

Comment: Step one in debugging this is probably to break down that `RUN` command; instead of `RUN a && b && c && d`, have four separate `RUN` commands.  Which one fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit code 8 is [likely from `wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) meaning an error response from the server. As an example, this path that the Dockerfile tries to wget from isn't valid anymore: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

From the issues on the repo, it appears that [Apache version 3.0.1 is no longer valid](https://github.com/cordon-thiago/airflow-spark/issues/15) so you should override the APACHE_SPARK version to 3.0.2 with a [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg):

```sh
docker build --rm --force-rm \
  --build-arg spark_version=3.0.2 \
  -t jupyter/pyspark-notebook:3.0.2 .
```

---

**EDIT**

See comment below for more, the command that worked was:

```sh
docker build --rm --force-rm \
  --build-arg spark_version=3.1.1 \
  --build-arg hadoop_version=2.7 \
  -t jupyter/pyspark-notebook:3.1.1 .
```

And updated spark checksum to reflect the version for 3.1.1: https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz.sha512

For this answer to be relevant in the future, it will likely need to update versions and checksum again for the latest spark/hadoop versions.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem.
In addtion to adding --build-arg to override the versions for spark_version and hadoop_version:
```
docker build --rm --force-rm -t jupyter/pyspark-notebook:3.1.1 . --build-arg spark_version=3.1.1 --build-arg hadoop_version=2.7
```
I also had to update the spark_checksum in the docker file to match the new  spark link:
https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz.sha512

Comment: @ilovejames Glad it helped. Appreciate that you came back and said what else you had to do to make it work!